# SQL execution script

Tags: sql, sql-server

We want to Execute the "close" for the old open PO in our system. We pull the scripts below but shows nothing. see the screenshot and scripts below. Where did it get wrong and what the execution query would be?

```
 select purchase_order.ID, order_date, status 
    from purchase_order 
    where STATUS = 'r' and order_date < 2020-01-01
```

[image: SQL sripts]

[image: ERP results]

Answer (score 1):

```
select purchase_order.ID, order_date, status 
from purchase_order 
where STATUS = 'r' and order_date < '2020-01-01'
```

Order_date should be in ''

Comment: thanks Sergey. what is the execution query to close for those open orders?

Comment: Welcome. I am sorry, but I haven't got any idea how to close these opened orders. It might be you need to update status-column to some value

Comment: No worries at all. Yes, I want to execute the query for close at once instead of going back to the system and close them manually...I am not sure what is the execution script for this..